# Boole's inequality approach.

Tags: probability, inequality

I am trying to solve this homework problem. I am curious even how to approach this.

[image]

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLyQG.png)

The first one I said, that something largest greater than epsilon means everything else would be larger too. So it's union of all those inequalities and applied Boole's inequality and fixed it. What about this one? The second one. I am out of ideas here.

What books can one read to solve this?

Comment: Why downvote? I am not a liar. I am working on these problems and trying my best. Atleast let me know what to study to be able to solve this

Comment: @amWhy ...........

Comment: newuser: I edited your post to include your equations.  Is that why you mentioned me? (@amWhy...) Is there a problem with the edit?  If so you are free to undo my edit.

Comment: @amWhy.: Hey no, I thought you downvoted. Thanks for your help. By the way any idea what to study to solve this? Really I have no clue.

Comment: It is the same. $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i > \epsilon$ implies at least one of $X_i > \epsilon / n$. The contraposition is when all of $X_i \leq \epsilon / n$, it implies $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq \epsilon$

Comment: @BGM.:Yes but even if atleast one of them is bigger, how can I generalize. I cant put it in any union rule. (It is more like "or")(x1 is greater than ep/n or x2 is gt ep/n...blah blah). Can we apply bool's here?

Comment: @BGM.: Wait a sec, you mean atleast one of them is true that means the sum in the RHS is >=1 atleast. That means iLHS would always be <= 1 which is true because probability of soemthing is always <=1? This is what u meant?

Comment: So can you relate "At least one is true" to the logical operator "or"?

Comment: @BGM.: Yes. I can. And I guess I got your answer. Why don;t you post it as your answer(if you want) I can upvote and select for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i > \epsilon \Rightarrow \exists i \in \{1, 2, \ldots,n\},  X_i > \frac {\epsilon} {n} $$

If this proposition is not intuitive enough, the contraposition (which is logically equivalent) maybe easier to understand:

$$ \forall i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}, X_i \leq \frac {\epsilon} {n} \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq \epsilon$$

Therefore,

$$ \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i > \epsilon\right\} 
\subseteq \left\{ \exists i \in \{1, 2, \ldots,n\},  X_i > \frac {\epsilon} {n}\right\} 
= \bigcup_{i=1}^n \left\{X_i > \frac {\epsilon} {n}\right\}$$

As a result,

$$ \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i > \epsilon\right)
\leq \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n \left\{X_i > \frac {\epsilon} {n}\right\}\right) 
\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}\left(X_i > \frac {\epsilon} {n}\right)  $$

where the last inequality is the Boole's inequality.